# Write a program to count the number of times a character appears in the File. (Case insensitive... 'a' and 'A' are considered to be the same)

Tags: c, file-handling

I have to write a program to count the number of times a character appears in the File. (Case insensitive... 'a' and 'A' are considered to be the same)

```
     #include<stdio.h>

     #include<stdlib.h>

     #include<ctype.h>

    int main()

   {

    FILE *fp1;

   char ch,f[100],c,d;

   int ct=0;

   printf("Enter the file name\n");

   scanf("%s",f);   

   fp1=fopen(f,"r");

  printf("Enter character:");

  scanf(" %c",&c);

  do 

  { 

    printf("%c",ch);

    ch=fgetc(fp1);

    d=toupper(ch);

    printf("%c",d);

    if(c==d)

    ++ct;

    }while(ch!=EOF);

   fclose(fp1);

  printf("\n");

  printf("%d",ct);

  return 0;

  }`
```

This is the program I have written but the output i'm getting it is..

> [ a.txt contains the string- 
>   aaa ]

Now when running the program this is the output which I get  :

> Enter the file name
>
> a.txt
>
> Enter character:a
>
> aAaAa
>
> 0

What am I doing wrong here ??

Comment: After you get the value of `c` convert it to uppercase

Comment: i need my output to be aAaAaA 3

Comment: Yes.. But you enter `a` and then convert all the characters in file to uppercase. Then how can `a=A`?? . So convert `a`(input character) also to upper case.

Comment: Yes. I dit. Its working now. Simple logic. didnt think of it. :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to check if the character to be searched is equal to a character in the file **or its uppercase version** and if it is, increment `ct`.

Simply change

```
if(c==d)
```

to

```
if(c==d || c==ch)
```

Other problem: `ch` is not initialized here

```
printf("%c",ch);
```

in the first iteration of the `do...while` loop. Fix it by moving the above `printf` after

```
ch=fgetc(fp1);
```

Also, add a check to see if `ch` is not `EOF` before printing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you input 'a', and you transform all your characters toUpper()... It can definitely not work ;:=)

Comment: please help me . Then what should i change

Comment: add a c = c.toUpper() ... After your input

Comment: @LaurentLequenne `c = c.toUpper()`? This is C

Comment: yah toupper(c) then :=)

Answer (score -1):

This code works i guess.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main()
{

    FILE *fp1;
    char c;
    char ai,s;
    char fname[20];
    int count=0;

    clrscr();
    printf("enter the character to be counted:");
    scanf("%c",&ai);
    s=toupper(ai);
    printf("enter the file name :");
    scanf("%s",&fname);
    fp1=fopen(fname,"r");

    if(fp1==NULL)
    {
        printf("cannot open this file");
    }

    do
    {
        c=fgetc(fp1);
        if(c==ai || c==s)
        {
            count=count+1;
        }
    }

    while(c != EOF);
    printf("\nFILE '%s' has %d instances of letter %c",fname,count,ai);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Please don't just dump you code. Explain your train of thoughts so we can understand your answer. Thanks.